# Multiple resource in tastypie

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

i'm using Tastypie to build an REST API. so i have this class :

so i have a classe ToolBox and with tastypie i can access it by

http://somthing.com/api/toolbox/list/
http://somthing.com/api/toolbox/list/5

but it's possible to add new mothod like "http://somthing.com/api/toolbox/stats/5" to obtain many stats of selected toolbox ?

or it possible to create a Stat class not based on a model to give stats on ToolBox, User and many other stats?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this.  It is a decorator that helps you add custom actions to Tastypie Resources:
https://github.com/thelonecabbage/django-tastypie-actions

Answer (score 3):

You should not mix resource urls, it is hackish and probably will get overly complex. You can use the dehydrate cycle to add non-Model fields to your existing ToolboxResource or if there is a relationship you can nest one resource within another see: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230607/how-to-combine-mutiple-resources-in-django-tastypie/11232187#11232187)

[tastypie docs: dehydrate cycle](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=dehydrate#dehydrate-foo)